# How can I return hash pairs of keys that sum up to less than a maximum value?

Tags: ruby, hash, key, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

Given this hash:

```rb
numsHash = {5=>10, 3=>9, 4=>7, 2=>5, 20=>4}
```

How can I return the key-value pair of this hash if and when the sum of its keys would be under or equal to a maximum value such as `10`?

The expected result would be something like:

```rb
newHash = { 5=>10, 3=>9, 2=>5 }
```

because the sum of these keys equals 10.

I've been obsessing with this for hours now and can't find anything that leads up to a solution.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). That means first you need to solve the knapsack problem for what keys to pick and then in a second step you can just use [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to generate the result hash with the keys you computed in the first step.

Comment: "How can I return the key-value pair of this hash when and if the sum of its keys would be under or equal a max_number" doesn't make sense because you could just choose the key-value pair with the smallest key, here `{ 2=>5 }`, provided that key is no greater than "max_number". I suspect the problem is, "Given a hash and an integer, find a collection of the hash's keys whose sum *equals* the given integer and return a slice of the hash with those keys. Return `nil` if no such collection exists. If I am correct the problem is an equal-weight knapsack problem, as @spickermann suspects.

Comment: For the OP: The use of variables like *numHash* are a pretty good indicator that someone is new to Ruby where snakecase (e.g. *num_hash*) is more idiomatic. We *want* more people to use Ruby, so take it as gentle advice rather than criticism. Also, I suspect the downvotes are because you didn't "show your work." While I explain above why I don't think that's bad in this particular case, as a new user on SO you can avoid negative votes/flags in future by providing more details about what you've already tried, and by avoiding the mistakes itemized at https://idownvotedbecau.se/.

Comment: @Todd, you may be right that the downvote and vote to close may be due to the fact that no effort to solve the problem has been demonstrated (some members demand that), but it could also be due to the fact that the question makes no sense (see the first sentence in my comment above) and the OP has not clarified the question. It is the upvote that I find puzzling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

1. In the first section, I provide some context and a well-commented working example of how to solve the defined knapsack problem in a matter of microseconds using a little brute force and some Ruby core classes.
2. In the second section, I refactor and expand on the code to demonstrate the conversion of the knapsack solution into output *similar* to what you want, although (as explained and demonstrated in the answer below) the correct output when there are multiple results must be a collection of Hash objects rather than a single Hash unless there are additional selection criteria not included in your original post.
3. Please note that this answer uses syntax and classes from Ruby 3.0, and was specifically tested against Ruby 3.0.3. While it *should* work on Ruby 2.7.3+ without changes, and with most currently-supported Ruby 2.x versions with some minor refactoring, your mileage may vary.

### Solving the Knapsack Problem with Ruby Core Methods

This seems to be a variant of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), where you're trying to optimize filling a container of a given size. This is actually a complex problem that is NP-complete, so a real-world application of this type will have many different solutions and possible algorithmic approaches.

I do not claim that the following solution is optimal or suitable for general purpose solutions to this class of problem. However, it works very quickly given the provided input data from your original post.

Its suitability is primarily based on the fact that you have a fairly small number of Hash keys, and the built-in Ruby 3.0.3 core methods of [Hash#permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#method-i-permutation) and [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) are fast enough to solve this particular problem in anywhere from 44-189 microseconds on my particular machine. That seems more than sufficiently fast for the problem as currently defined, but your mileage and real objectives may vary.

```rb
# This is the size of your knapsack.
MAX_VALUE = 10

# It's unclear why you need a Hash or what you plan to do with the values of the
# Hash, but that's irrelevant to the problem. For now, just grab the keys.
#
# NB: You have to use hash rockets or the parser complains about using an
# Integer as a Symbol using the colon notation and raises SyntaxError.
nums_hash = {5 => 10, 3 => 9, 4 => 7, 2 => 5, 20 => 4}
keys = nums_hash.keys

# Any individual element above MAX_VALUE won't fit in the knapsack anyway, so
# discard it before permutation.
keys.reject! { _1 > MAX_VALUE }

# Brute force it by evaluating all possible permutations of your array, dropping
# elements from the end of each sub-array until all remaining elements fit.
keys.permutation.map do |permuted_array|
  loop { permuted_array.sum > MAX_VALUE ? permuted_array.pop : break }
  permuted_array
end
```

### Returning an Array of Matching Hashes

The code above just returns the list of keys that will fit into your knapsack, but per your original post you then want to return a Hash of matching key/value pairs. The problem here is that you actually have more than one set of Hash objects that will fit the criteria, so your collection should actually be an Array rather than a single Hash. Returning only a single Hash would basically return the original Hash minus any keys that exceed your *MAX_VALUE*, and that's unlikely to be what's intended.

Instead, now that you have a list of keys that fit into your knapsack, you can iterate through your original Hash and use [Hash#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) to return an Array of *unique* Hash objects with the appropriate key/value pairs. One way to do this is to use [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to call [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) on each Hash element in the subarrays to convert the final result to an Array of Hash objects. Next, you should call [Enumerable#unique](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) to remove any Hash that is equivalent except for its internal ordering.

For example, consider this redesigned code:

```rb
MAX_VALUE = 10

def possible_knapsack_contents hash
  hash.keys.reject! { _1 > MAX_VALUE }.permutation.map do |a|
    loop { a.sum > MAX_VALUE ? a.pop : break }; a
  end.sort
end

def matching_elements_from hash
  possible_knapsack_contents(hash).map do |subarray|
    subarray.map { |i| hash.select { |k, _| k == i } }.
      reduce({}) { _1.merge _2 }
  end.uniq
end

hash = {5 => 10, 3 => 9, 4 => 7, 2 => 5, 20 => 4}
matching_elements_from hash
```

Given the defined input, this would yield 24 hashes if you didn't address the uniqueness issue. However, by calling #uniq on the final Array of Hash objects, this will correctly yield the 7 *unique* hashes that fit your defined criteria if not necessarily the single Hash you seem to expect:

```rb
[{2=>5, 3=>9, 4=>7},
 {2=>5, 3=>9, 5=>10},
 {2=>5, 4=>7},
 {2=>5, 5=>10},
 {3=>9, 4=>7},
 {3=>9, 5=>10},
 {4=>7, 5=>10}]
```

Comment: Do you perhaps want to use `keys.combination` rather than `keys.permutation`?

Comment: @Chris #combination returns an n-tuple. You'd have to refactor other code to make that work, and I don't see how iterating over tuple sizes is any better than dropping elements from a permuted set of arrays. If you have a faster or more effective solution using #combination, I encourage you to post it as a separate answer.